# Error occured in Contact Form 7 in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I've installed the plugin **Contact Form 7** on my **Wordpress** page and put the short code in the `index.php`.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form 1 "Kontaktformulär 1"]' ); ?>
```

It shows up as it should but when I'm gonna use it, it doesn't work. I get an error message saying:

**"An error has occured, please try again later"**

Anyone knows what can be wrong? I'm using the latest version of **Wordpress** and **Contact Form 7**

Answer (score 2):

Easy. See this [Contact Form 7 FAQ](http://contactform7.com/faq/)

Answer (score -1):

I've got some troubleshooting tip you can try.
Try disabling other plug-ins you've installed. :-)